# just statically linking to libboost_thread triggers access violation crash on startup

Tags: visual-c++, boost-thread

I am dealing with the following setup:
A C++/CLI dll links to a static lib, which itself links against a static build of libboost_thread.
Without linking against libboost_thread the .exe, that loads the dll, runs fine.
I can even link to libboost_system and it still all runs fine.
At the very moment that I am linking against libboost_thread, the application always crashes with an access violation on startup before even entering any of my code.
This even happens if I am not including any boost header, I don't have to use anything from boost. Just linking against boosts threading library is enough to let the app crash.

I am using boost 1.53.0 and the prebuilt windows libs from http://boost.teeks99.com/ (especially libboost_thread-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib in both,the 32 and the 64bit version, tirggers this issue).

Any idea, what can cause that?

Comment: Is there anything in the output screen? There must be some log file.

Comment: did you find the solution yet??

Comment: No, we have not researched this issue further, as we have decided to not use boost in that project for now.